# Mango reminders in locked screen

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I'm creating the option for the users of an app, to get reminders of events from the app. So I add the reminders using the ScheduledActionService, and set the NavigationUri to a xaml page in my app.

When I keep the phone active until the reminder occurs, it works fine, and if I click the reminder, I go to my app.

But...

Most often, a reminder will show up at some time where the phone is locked. And in that case, the only thing that I can do is snooze or dismiss the reminder. Nothing happens if I click the title/content, and it is not possible to unlock the phone, because the reminder overlays it.

So how should this be handled? Is there a bug in the behavior somehow? How am I supposed to get the user back into the app when the reminder pops up on a locked screen?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have the same problem right now with an app I'm working on and it's SUPER annoying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it seems to be a bug on WP7 Mango.

Another one is that when a toast pops up if the phone is locked and autopowers off, the toast is dismissed. So user might never be informed about a toast (ie, phone inside pocket).

Answer (score 2):

That's intended behavior.

> If you want to unlock your phone, you'll need to dismiss the reminder first.
>
> If you get a notification, you can tap it before you unlock the phone and you'll be automatically taken to the notification after you unlock your phone.

Source: http://www.microsoft.com/windowsphone/en-us/howto/wp7/basics/locked-phone-things-you-can-still-do.aspx

Comment: Actually, it's sort of a mix of those two. The notification that is mentioned here is a push-notification. And that works as explained here. But a reminder does not. As it states, I have to dismiss or cancel the reminder before I can unlock the phone. But if I get the reminder when the phone is not locked, I have a third option, which is pressing the text of the reminder, and start the app that set the reminder in the first place. I would like it if the reminder worked similarly to the push notifications.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, Morten is right. Reminder that pops up when the phone is locked does not allow user to tap on the reminder (anywhere but two buttons). In other words, description on the MS link is not correct for regular reminders.